# Convert hex file to int array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, int, hex

A have a text file hex like:

```
FE 99 77 88
```

I want to convert to int array. So how to complete it? 
I'm using c# console. And I just started programming.
Thanhks you!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You'll get a much better response if you show your code: see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, especially [ask], before posting your next question here. We're glad to help, but we're not a homework completion or code writing service; we expect you to make some effort to solve it yourself first. Good luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try code below.  I made it very simple and clear :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);

            string inputLine = "";

            List<byte> data = new List<byte>();
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] splitArray = inputLine.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();

                foreach(string hexNumberStr in splitArray)
                {
                    byte hexNumber = byte.Parse(hexNumberStr, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                    data.Add(hexNumber);
                }
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be simpler to use `File.ReadLines` to iterate over the lines in the file. If you *really* want to use `StreamReader` directly, I'd at least advise using a `using` statement - particularly as the OP is new to C#; you don't want them to get into bad habits.

Comment: With large files StreamReader is the preferred method.  It doesn't read the entire file into memory.

Comment: Neither does File.ReadLines. that's not the same thing as File.ReadAllLines. And if you want a reader, File.OpenText is a simpler way of creating one, IMO... But you'd still want a using statement.

Comment: @jdweng You have a good point. Thanks!